# How to validate if you enter the same data in the textbox? (no database needed)

Tags: javascript

I'm so new in javascript and still learning. I have a form and a table. The form needs to fill out the email, fullname, username and name dynamically. However, I'm stuck in this validation. The validation is to check if that email or username has already been added recently and the pop up will alert "The +username/email+ already exist. The email/username are related to +fullname". Can someone help me with this?

Comment: what you have tried share your code ???

Comment: Post some code!

Comment: You have an HTML form and a database table,correct?  Do you have any server-side code that will write to the database?  And, if so, why don't you have the server code check for a current entry in the database, and send back an "OK" HTML response (for a new entry), or a "User already exists" HTML response otherwise?

Comment: I recommend you update your question and specify that you are not using a database to avoid misunderstandings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the innertext of every td of every tr of your table using this code. All you have to do is in the for loop check if the name and email are not same as any row. If in any row they are then show the alert that name and email already exist and return.

```
 var table = document.getElementById("vdCharac");
    for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
       //iterate through rows
       //rows would be accessed using the "row" variable assigned in the for loop
       for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
         //iterate through columns
         //columns would be accessed using the "col" variable assigned in the for loop
       }  
    }
```

Comment: hi @rexroxm what code should I add inside the forloop? I'm sorry I'm a newbie in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to check your db to see if email or username it's already been taken you'll need ajax: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_database.asp
You'll have to create a php page that return every username or email and control it with ajax.

Answer (score 0):

```
else {
    // first check if an item with that name and email exists
    var found = false;
    // by looping through the table row by row
    for(var i = 0; i < table.rows.length && !found; i++)
        // if you want to check if name OR emailAdd exists use || instead of &&
        if(table.rows[i].cells[0].textContent == name && table.rows[i].cells[1].textContent == emailAdd)
            found = true;

     // if fount alert the message
     if(found) {
         alert("An entry with email '" + emailAdd + "' and name '" + name + "' already exists!");
         return false;
     }
     // else insert a new row
     else {
         var row = table.insertRow(); //this will add a row to the table
         var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
         var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
         cell1.textContent = name; // use textContent instead of innerHTML
         cell2.textContent = emailAdd; // here too

         // uncomment these following to lines to enhance the user interactivity by reseting the inputs if an item is inserted
         //form.enterName.value = "";
         //form.enterEmail.value = "";

         return true;
    }    
}
```